# Getting "org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderValueException" error for a "post" method on an API

Tags: cucumber, bdd, rest-assured, web-api-testing, karate

The exception I am getting is

> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderValueException: Too many "Content-Type" header values: "[application/json, application/json]"

I was passing a request with content type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' when I was getting this error. When I tried by not passing the content-type, I was still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the latest Karate version and you should be able to solve this problem: https://github.com/intuit/karate